# Нарисовать линию на Button при нажатии

Tags: c#, winforms

Я сделал простое API для вкладок на winforms, я хочу что бы под кнопкой активной вкладки была красивая линия, но из-за изменения FlatAppearance и отсутствия на них ивента я не могу это сделать корректно.

При наводке(MouseEnter)/отводке(MouseLeave)/клика(Click) Background(По настройкам FlatAppearance) меняет цвет, при чём так, что ивент ChangeBackground не вызывается.
Я пробовал использовать выше указанные ивенты, но прорисовка FlatAppearance похоже идёт после моей рисовки, из-за чего моя линия сразу же стирается.

Рисую я с помощью `g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 255)), rects)`

Когда нажал и не двигал мышкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После отвода мышки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

API:

```
internal class TabsAPI
{
    private int select = 0;
    private Panel TabOwner;
    private Panel Display;
    internal List<Tab> Tabs = new List<Tab>();
    internal TabsAPI(ref Panel panel, ref Panel formDisplay)
    {
        TabOwner = panel;
        Display = formDisplay;
    }
    internal void AddTab(Tab tab)
    {
        Tabs.Add(tab);
        tab.TabButton.Click += Click;
        TabOwner.Controls.Add(tab.TabButton);
    }
    internal void Init()
    {
        ReloadTab();
    } 
    internal void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int preSelect = select;
        select = ((Control)sender).TabIndex - 1000;
        if (preSelect != select)
        {
            Tabs[preSelect].TabButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            ReloadTab();
            Graphics preSelectG = Tabs[preSelect].TabButton.CreateGraphics();
            preSelectG.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56)), Tabs[select].rects);
        }
        Graphics selectG = Tabs[select].TabButton.CreateGraphics();
        selectG.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 56, 255)), Tabs[select].rects);
    }
    private void ReloadTab()
    {
        foreach (Control control in Display.Controls)
            Display.Controls.Remove(control);
        Tabs[select].TabButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Tabs[select].ShowForm.TopLevel = false;
        Display.Controls.Add(Tabs[select].ShowForm);
        Tabs[select].ShowForm.Show();
    }
    internal class Tab
    {
        internal Tab(string name, Form form, int index, Size size)
        {
            Name = name;
            ShowForm = form;
            Size = size;
            rects = new PointF[4] { new PointF(0, size.Height), new PointF(size.Width, size.Height), new PointF(size.Width, size.Height - 2), new PointF(0, size.Height - 2) };
            TabButton = new Button();
            TabButton.TabIndex = index + 1000;
            TabButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56);
            TabButton.Font = new Font("Open Sans Semibold", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 204);
            TabButton.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
            TabButton.Location = new Point(0, size.Height * index);
            TabButton.Name = name;
            TabButton.Text = name;
            TabButton.Size = size;
            TabButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            TabButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            TabButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            TabButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(62, 62, 62);
            TabButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 69, 69);
            TabButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            g = TabButton.CreateGraphics();
            TabButton.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => { TabButton.Font = new Font("Open Sans Semibold", 12.1F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 204); });
            TabButton.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => { TabButton.Font = new Font("Open Sans Semibold", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 204); });
            TabButton.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 255)), rects));
            TabButton.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 255)), rects));
            TabButton.Click += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 255)), rects));
        }
        private Graphics g { get; set; }
        internal PointF[] rects { get; set; }
        internal string Name{ get; set; }
        internal Button TabButton { get; set; }
        internal Form ShowForm { get; set; }
        internal Size Size { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вызываю:

```
TabsAPI menuTabs = new TabsAPI(ref panel4, ref panel5);
menuTabs.AddTab(new TabsAPI.Tab("DooDHack", new Main_Window.DooDHack(), 0, new Size(145, 30)));
menuTabs.AddTab(new TabsAPI.Tab("Config", new Main_Window.ConfigMenu(), 1, new Size(145, 30)));
menuTabs.AddTab(new TabsAPI.Tab("Settings", new Main_Window.Settings(), 2, new Size(145, 30)));
menuTabs.AddTab(new TabsAPI.Tab("Guard", new Main_Window.Guard(), 3, new Size(145, 30)));
menuTabs.Init();
```

Может есть какие-нибудь методы прорисовки?(Крайне не хочу наследовать Button и что-то с ней делать)

Так же можете оценить начальный дизайн(У меня с ним обычно всё очень плохо)

Comment: Ох не то вы выбрали для UI, ох не то... Хотите красивостей - мой вам совет, берите WPF или что-либо новее, ибо там ваша задумка решается в пару строк XAML, без единой строки C#.

Comment: Плюсую за WPF. Или если хочется острых ощущений и топовых технологий, то Windows App SDK. Винформы - это вообще не про нормальный UI.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а если я мазохист?

Comment: Если мазохист, то чтобы контролить отрисовку контрола на винформах, надо от него наследоваться и переопределять `OnPaint`.

Comment: @Yotic Программирование -- это боль. В принципе. Побудь мазохистом в правильном направлении - помучься и изучи WPF. Это будет сложно, это будет больно, зато с пользой. Пользы от мазохизма в винформсах - ноль.

Comment: @Andrew не, WPF это слишком жестко. Какой-то XAML непонятный, какие-то стили, какие-то привязки данных (в винформах они тоже есть, но это тайна), какой-то MVVM. Ужас, это с нуля надо учиться писать приложения же.

Comment: Что касается дизайна - вот приложение [WinUI 3 Controls Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/p/winui-3-controls-gallery/9p3jfpwwdzrc?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), поставьте из винстора, полистайте контролы, посмотрите дизайн, это бесплатно.

Comment: @aepot, Спасибо, но я сам хочу всё узко реализовать, без сторонних библиотек( так бы я guana crack взял)

Comment: Боюсь вас расстраивать, но Windows App SDK - не сторонняя библиотека. Сырая, кривая, но своя родная. WPF кстати тоже вполне себе официальный проект Microsoft.

Comment: Я про WinUI 3 Controls Gallery, а вы про что?

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 пути:

1. Сделать свой элемент, унаследованный у Button и уже в нём OnPaint перехватывать.
2. Сделать через панель и свои ивенты

Я выбрал через панель, Я просто сделал свой элемент(Не унаследованный) в котором прописал часть полей из панели, а часть и того что я хочу(LineHight, LineColor, Location), сделал пару методов(Render, Init) и добавил ивенты(Click, MouseLeave, MouseEnter)

Это не конечный ответ, если у вас идея лучше - пишите

Answer (score 0):

Каким-то сложным путем вы идете. Отрисовка на контроле происходит в двух местах: базовая часть - внутренний метод OnPaint, который может быть переопределен в наследнике если очень хочется, и пользовательская часть в обработчике события Paint, которое инициируется после базовой отрисовки.

Таким образом, для того чтобы на вашей кнопке что-то рисовалось независимо от настроек стиля, необходимо использовать событие Paint. А чтобы это происходило только при определенных условиях, то подписку на это событие надо сделать динамической.

К примеру ваш случай - при входе курсора в область кнопки рисуем что-то пока мышь не покинет область кнопки, нужно статически (в момент создания кнопки или в конструкторе формы, не важно) подписаться на два события MouseEnter и MouseLeave. В MouseEnter мы подписываемся на событие Paint кнопки в которую вошли, в MouseLeave - отписываемся от этого события.

Простой пример без конкретного рисования и всяких проверок безопасности, это сами уже экспериментируйте:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //событие добавлено в дизайнере
        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Paint += CustomDraw;
        }

        //событие добавлено в дизайнере
        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Paint -= CustomDraw;
        }

        //этот обработчик будем динамически подписывать на событие Paint
        private void CustomDraw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //тут что-то рисуете поверх кнопки
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 5, 5, 20, 5);
        }
    }
```